Change a matrix of base with respect a special base consisted of a kernel and a rowspace
I have got a matrix $B$ $m \times n$. I found a basis of its Kernel and of its rowspace so both together form a basis of $\Re^n$. I have seen in an article that you can now express a matrix $A$ $n \times n$ in this basis so you get the following matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
        A_{RR} & A_{RK} \\ A_{KR} & A_{KK}
\end{pmatrix}
I cant figure out which are the steps to arrive to this block matrix. Thank you!!
